# avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1

Tags: atmega, fuses, bootloader, fuse-bits

when trying to program the fuses I get this known error message:

`$ sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U hfuse:w:0x05:m`

> avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check.
>
> avrdude done.  Thank you.

Here's with -vvvv:
`$ sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U hfuse:w:0x05:m -vvvv`: **pastebin.com/mcdyiHYq**

Adding -B20 or -B250 doesn't help.

-> I know exactly how I caused this: `$ sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U hfuse:w:0x11:m`. The wired thing is the output and that it shows that `E:11` is set instead of `H:11`. **pastebin.com/wE7uwC31** Why did avrdude set the wrong fuse :\ and is this a bug in avrdude?

-> -B250 worked one time when I needed it: First I did `$ sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U lfuse:w:E3:m`, but when I tried to set it back to `0x62` I got `initialization failed, rc=-1`, added `-B250` and `$ sudo avrdude -c usbtiny -p m328p -U lfuse:w:E3:m` worked. The thing is, it doesn't work now when I set the other fuse to `0x11` as described.

-> Everything is well connected because if I try a different same ATmega328P-PU chip, it works. So it has something to do with this `0x11` fuse setting I did. And also the code is running on this chip is still working and the attached LCD shows correct results.

[This](http://eleccelerator.com/fusecalc/fusecalc.php?chip=atmega328p&LOW=62&HIGH=11&EXTENDED=DA&LOCKBIT=FF) is what the `0x11` high fuse setting sets, but it's not like this setting means that it is set to "locked" or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you've programmed the RSTDISBL fuse bit, which means that ISP will no longer work. You will need to find or build a HVPP programmer in order to unprogram that fuse bit.

[more info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuHpA8OjblE)

Comment: The really bad thing about this is that I (explicitly) wrote hfuse:w:0x11:m, but the wrong fuse was set :\ Is this a bug in avrdude?

Comment: No. Setting a fuse bit to 0 programs it.

Comment: I don't understand your replay. Which fuse bit did I set to 0?

Comment: The RSTDISBL fuse bit.

Comment: The senseless thing with AVR fuse bits are that they use reverse logic for programming. Meaning that if you want to **enable** a fuse option, you need to program it with a **`0`** !